# PL/SQL Stored Procedure create tables

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I've been tasked with improving old PL/SQL and Oracle SQL legacy code.  In all there are around 7000 lines of code!  One aspect of the existing code that really surprises me is the previous coder needlessly created hundreds of lines of code by not writing any procedures or functions  - instead the coder essentially repeats the same code throughout.

For example, in the existing code there are literally 40 or more repetitions of  the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_clients
AS
    SELECT * FROM live.clients;

CREATE TABLE tmp_customers
AS
    SELECT * FROM live.customers;

CREATE TABLE tmp_suppliers
AS
    SELECT * FROM live.suppliers WHERE type_id = 1;

and many, many more.....
```

I'm very new to writing in PL/SQL, though I have recently purchased the excellent book "Oracle PL/SQL programming" by Steven Feuerstein.  However, as far as I can tell, I should be able to write a callable procedure such as:

```
procedure create_temp_table (new_table_nme in varchar(60)
  source_table in varchar(60))
IS
    s_query varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    s_query := 'CREATE TABLE ' + new_table_nme + 'AS SELECT * FROM ' + source_table;
   execute immediate s_query;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       IF SQLCODE = -955 THEN
           NULL;
       ELSE
           RAISE;
       END IF;
END;
```

I would then simply call the procedure as follows:

```
create_temp_table('tmp.clients', 'live.clients');
create_temp_table('tmp.customers', 'live.customers');
```

1. Is my proposed approach reasonable given the problem as stated?
2. Are the datatypes in the procedure call reasonable, ie should varchar2(60) be used, or is it possible to force the 'source_table' parameter to be a table name in the schema? What happens if the table name is more than 60 characters?
3. I want to be able to pass a third non-required parameter in cases where the data has to be restricted in a trivial way, ie to deal with cases "WHERE type_id = 1".  How do I modify the procedure to include a parameter that is only used occasionally and how would I modify the rest of the code.   I would probably add some sort of IF/ELSE statement to check whether the third parameter was not NULL and then construct the s_query accordingly.
4. How would I check that the table has actually been created successfully?
5. I want to trap for two other exceptions, namely

   - The new table (eg 'tmp.clients') already exists; and
   - The source table doesn't exist.

   Does the EXCEPTION as written handle these cases?
6. More generally, from where can I obtain the SQL error codes and their meanings?

Any suggested improvements to the code would be gratefully received.

Comment: just use global temporary tables.  The code to create tables makes me think the original person was familiar with SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You could get rid of a lot of code (gradually!) by using GLOBAL temporary tables. 
Execute immediate is not a bad practice but if there are other options then they should be used.  Global temp tables are common where you want to extract and transform data but once processed you don't need it anymore until the next load. Each user can only see the data they insert and no redo logs are generated. You can [index the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946353/create-index-on-global-temporary-table) for faster querying if required.

Something like this

-- Create table

```
create global temporary table GT_CLIENTS
(
  id                    NUMBER(10) not null,
  Client_id             NUMBER(10) not null,
  modified_by_id        NUMBER(10),
  transaction_id        NUMBER(10),
  local_transaction_id  VARCHAR2(30) not null,
  last_modified_date_tz TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE not null
)
on commit preserve rows;
```

I recommend the on commit preserve rows option so that you can debug your procedure and see what went into the table.

Usage would be

```
INSERT INTO GT_CLIENTS
SELECT * FROM live.clients;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I understand that Global temporary tables can be used to store the results of complex queries.  However, I can't see the benefit of what you are proposing if all I am doing is essentially copying an existing table from a live production environment into my own schema.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the point, your solution requires a substantial amount of code to be written for every Global Temporary Table, ie separate code would need to be written for GT_CLIENTS, GT_CUSTOMERS, GT_SUPPLIERS etc.  This is the very thing I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I accept there are other benefits to Global Temporary Tables (presumably lower memory or storage space), and I'm happy to be persuaded otherwise but at the moment I can't see how your solution as proposed is of benefit to me purely due to the amount of code that would need to be written.

Comment: @user2948208 If you were to tell us what the point of the code is an answer with more depth could be supplied.  From a high level view dropping and creating tables on a regular basis is not a best practice unless there is a business case of some complexity. As well the possibilities of misuse by other users who don't know the intent are endless.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the route you want to take to minimize changes, then the error for source table does not exist is -942 which you will want to stop for rather than continuing as your temp table would not have been created. Similarly, just continuing if you get an object already exists error will be problematic as you will not have reloaded it with the new data - the create failed so the table still has the data from the last run. So I would definitely do some more thinking about your exception handler.

That said, I also concur that this is generally not the best way to do things. Creating and dropping objects in a multi-user environment is a disaster in the making, and seems a silly waste of resources when there are more appropriate options available.

Comment: Thanks for advising the code -942.  As I've commented above, I'm more than happy to be do things in the "best way possible", but you've not really explained how, other than to say you concur with the previous person.  I'm possibly missing the point of Global Temporary Tables for this purpose as it appears a substantial amount of code would need to be written per such table.  Also, this is not really a multi-user environment, albeit it is true that the tables are required only for a brief period of time as inputs into larger queries

Comment: Yes, you need to create your global temporary tables, but once created you just insert into them as you are doing with the current create statements. So there is no significant additional coding once they are in your schema and you eliminate the overhead of creating/dropping objects, and GTTs do not generate redo logs or rollback information, thus significantly cutting back on the overhead of inserting data into them.